# Unity Invalid cast Exception when using method in custom dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some question, (sorry, I not good at Eng)

first, explain my project structure

CoreNet lib project include enum type named PACKET_TYPE,

MmoCore lib project include enum type named CONTENT_TYPE, and this project  refer to "CoreNet"

finally unity project refer to CoreNet, MmoCore dll at plugins folder

and Invalid cast exception is occur when I call method "SerWrite"

SerWrite method is below [this method is in MmoCore]

```
void SerWrite()
{
 // NetStream ns, PACKET_TYPE pt in packet class

 //NetStream is just Custom Stream class
 //PACKET_TYPE is in CoreNet dll.
 Translate.Write(ns, pt);
}
```

so, my script in unity sample

```
void Start()
{
 var tmpP = PACKET_TYPE.SOME;
 var ns = new NetStream();
//non exception
 Translate.Write(ns, tmpP);

 HelloReq p = new HelloReq();
//unity throw invalid cast exception 
 p.SerWrite();
}
```

how can i fix it..?

Comment: Try ```p.SerWrite(ns, tmpP)```.

Comment: sorry, that's typo lol; I refix it

Comment: All I can guess is that ```ns``` and ```pt``` variables don't match the signature of ```Translate.Write``` function without more information.